# How i Getting records from two tables in laravel or how i can match the date with second table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get records from a table in Laravel that is already linked to another table

Table name 1: ProductStock 
Table name 2: Sales is linked to table name two using user_id column.

I want to get records from product stock table and sales where the following

```
->whereBetween('created_at', array($thirdweekdata, $fourthweekdata))



          //I have tried this but it only get from ProductStock table..but I want this 
         wherebetween to be from sales table

         $fourth =  ProductStock::where('status',1)
          ->whereBetween('created_at', array($thirdweekdata, $fourthweekdata))
         ->get();
```

Comment: what's relationship between product_stock and sales?

Comment: Product stock have one to many relationship with Sales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the relationship method named `sales` in ProductStock Model:

```php
    public function sales()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Sale::class);
    }
```

use `with` closure, it will return the product_stocks and their sales both between the `$thirdweekdata` and `$fourthweekdata`.

```php
ProductStock::where('status', 1)
            ->whereBetween('created_at', array($thirdweekdata, $fourthweekdata))
            ->with(['sales' => function($query) use ($thirdweekdata, $fourthweekdata) {
               $query->whereBetween('created_at', array($thirdweekdata, $fourthweekdata));
            }])->get();
```

Comment: i am only interested in the sales created_at Date...i want the condition to be where the date of sales meets my wherebetween condition

Comment: Got this error....mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: Is `use ($thirdweekdata, $fourthweekdata)` missing in last subquery?

Comment: something is wrong..when i try to $item->sales->sum('sales') on the blade..it shows zero..meanwhile there is some sales on the sales table

Comment: @PPK you have a column named `sales` in your sales' record?

Comment: Yes i have that colume

Comment: did `$item->sales` return something?

Comment: returned zero in the view....ought to return the right data for the created_at date

Comment: check that data is belongs to that productStock and the created_at is between `$thirdweekdata`, `$fourthweekdata` or not

Comment: i tried this, still didnt not work... $request =  ProductStock::where('status',1)
         
          ->with(['sales' => function($query) use ($firstweekdata, $secondweekdata) {
               $query->whereBetween('created_at', array('2020-01-01', '2020-01-14'));
            }])->get();

Comment: @PPK let's talk in [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206193/user12737418-using-laravel-eloquent-to-get-records-from-database-where-the-differ)

Comment: oh okay this finally worked...the problem was from the created_at date format....would hv love to apreciate u but its against the principle here...pls can u give me a skype ID ..love to be ur friend...good friend